# Is there a way to test an email connection with the email gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rubygems

My rails application uses a Ruby script  retrieve an object from my database.
This objet is made of six fields that are:

- login
- password
- server
- port
- event_type_id
- active

Using the [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail), I'm using these informations to create a new Mail connection using Mail.defaults, like this in my MailConnection model:

```
def check
    begin
        puts("Attempting to connect to the specified email server...")
        Mail.defaults do
        retriever_method :pop3, :address => :server,
                :port         => :port,
                :user_name      => :login,
                :password      => :password,
                :enable_ssl      => false

        end
    rescue Exception => msg
        puts("Unconnected : #{msg}")
        false
    else
        puts("Connected")
        true
    end
end
```

I'm using this method in the Ruby script to check if the connection can be etablished before doing anything, but if I'm using invalid datas, it's still returning 'true' even if the network is unreachable. 
I'm all new to Ruby and, I would like to know what's wrong with my function;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner myself but have just been having a look at this.

**With net/pop**

```
require 'net/pop'

pop = Net::POP3.new('your.mail.server', optional_port)
pop.start('your_username', 'your_password') #should return an error if it fails
pop.started? #if you want to double check
```

**With the Mail gem**

If you'd rather use the Mail gem itself, the `connection` method in the POP3 retriever lets you get at those same methods by yielding a POP3 object to a block:

```
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address => :server,
    :port         => :port,
    :user_name      => :login,
    :password      => :password,
    :enable_ssl      => false
end

Mail.connection {|pop3| pop3.active? }
```

You might notice I used `started?` and `active?` interchangeably: they are the same POP3 instance method. One is simply aliased to the other.